# Using Resharper test runner with Jasmine 2.0

Tags: resharper, jasmine

I'm trying to use the Resharper (v8.2) test runner in VS2013 with Jasmine 2 but I'm having an issue calling a 'global' beforeEach

The spec file has a 'script reference' to a SpecHelper.js that has a call to beforeEach. The SpecHelper code is running but at the time that the SpecHelper is loaded Jasmine has not been loaded so beforeEach is not available.

The code looks like this:

```
///<reference path="../../../../jasmine/tests/BaseReferences.js"/>
```

then in the SpecHelper

```
beforeEach(function() {
    // do stuff here
}
```

This worked fine with the Jasmine 1.3 runner.

Does anybody know of anyway to fix this? I can't see any way to force Jasmine to load first but I may be missing the option

Comment: Had the same problem here at work, even tried a sample "Test" unit test.  Just now stumbled that it all works on 1.3 but not 2.0.  Lost two days productivity before finding that out.

My answer will be to use 1.3 for now as I cannot afford to lost any more time, and it works.

Newer not always better, I suppose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this is a bug in the Resharper runner (http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5513278#5513278)
It will be fixed in 8.2.1

Answer (score 3):

Have you changed the supported version of Jasmine to 2.0 in the ReSharper -> Options -> Unit Testing -> JavaScript page?

Comment: Hey Matt, yep, done that. Also tried adding Jasmine.cs as a reference in the spec, that didn't work either (surprise)

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could get the sample jasmine spec to work was to paste the code from the SpecHelper directly into the beforeEach.