# setFixtures is not defined: Jasmine tests failing when run by Resharper but not Chutzpah

Tags: jquery, jasmine, resharper, chutzpah

When running Jasmine tests from Resharper I get the following error for all tests, however the same tests succeed when initiated directly from the Chutzpah extension in Visual Studio.

```
Jasmine 2.0.0
finished in 0.106s
10 specs, 10 failures
Spec List | Failures
UI.tools Tests (name)
ReferenceError: setFixtures is not defined
ReferenceError: setFixtures is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:16026/Tests.js:19:9)
    at attemptSync (http://localhost:16026/jasmine.js:1510:12)
    at QueueRunner.run (http://localhost:16026/jasmine.js:1498:9)
    at QueueRunner.execute (http://localhost:16026/jasmine.js:1485:10)
    at Spec.Env.queueRunnerFactory (http://localhost:16026/jasmine.js:518:35)
    at Spec.execute (http://localhost:16026/jasmine.js:306:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:16026/jasmine.js:1708:37)
    at attemptAsync (http://localhost:16026/jasmine.js:1520:12)
    at QueueRunner.run (http://localhost:16026/jasmine.js:1496:16)
    at QueueRunner.execute (http://localhost:16026/jasmine.js:1485:10)
Expected 0 to be 1.
Error: Expected 0 to be 1.
    at stack (http://localhost:16026/jasmine.js:1293:17)
    at buildExpectationResult (http://localhost:16026/jasmine.js:1270:14)
    at Spec.Env.expectationResultFactory (http://localhost:16026/jasmine.js:484:18)
    at Spec.addExpectationResult (http://localhost:16026/jasmine.js:260:46)
    at Expectation.addExpectationResult (http://localhost:16026/jasmine.js:442:21)
    at Expectation.toBe (http://localhost:16026/jasmine.js:1209:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:16026/Tests.js:34:68)
    at attemptSync (http://localhost:16026/jasmine.js:1510:12)
    at QueueRunner.run (http://localhost:16026/jasmine.js:1498:9)
    at QueueRunner.execute (http://localhost:16026/jasmine.js:1485:10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr version - I upgraded Resharper and it works now.

I found the issue with some hunting. After reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25621148/jasmine-test-fails-running-in-vs2012-resharper-phantomjs) I went and checked the source of the page R# was generating, and sure enough while `jasmine.js` and `jasmine.css` were being loaded prior to my references, `resharper-utils.js`, `jasmine2ResharperReporter.js`, `jasmine-html.js` and `boot.js` were being loaded after. Most of these are dynamically generated by the tool so manually referencing them seemed to be the wrong thing to do.

I did some more looking and it turns out there's [a bug in Resharper 8.2.0](https://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5513278#5513278) - all I had to to was upgrade to a newer version (8.2.1+) and the issue was fixed.